# Android Mediaplayer Error Listener

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

do you Know more infomation about the Mediaplayer ErrorListener?

In my application I got this error

> 08-09 16:15:43.145: E/MediaPlayer(5972): error (1, -1010)

but I can't figure out which error is.

Comment: Post your code. What you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution testing different use case with Android mediaplayer.

Error ( 1, -1010) is raised when the streaming resources is not available ( 404 Http error)